# Don't restart my app if already it is open

Tags: java, javafx

I have a JavaFx App, packaged and installed on my desktop, but I have a problem when I open two instances, the second one gives me a database blocking error. My idea is to launch the application only once, and if the user tries to open another copy of the app that is already open to show the original instance and not open another (prevent it from running twice if it is already open).

Comment: Pretty similar, but not a exact match. The "show[ing] the original instance" which I assume means restore the window/bring it to the front...

Comment: problem solved I used Junique, I have been very useful your recommendation, thanks